# Hawt.io + Camel + Java DSL + route id

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

When using Spring XML to create routes, Hawt.io uses the route id as the name of the route.
How can I pass that name to Hawt.io when I create routes with Java DSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it like this:

```
from("file://").routeId("file_consumer")
```